# Regarding not able to get all the registered routes in node

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have used express router for us routing in my app

now i want to get list of all the registered routes but not able to get it

I have used route as follows

```
global.router = express.Router();
app.use('/api', require('./routes'));
```

I have declared all routes in routes.js file and that is working perfectly fine

but when I try to access the all the routes then it is return undefined in route

```
let allRoutes = app._router.stack.map(r => r.route.path)
```

Comment: What is `allRoutes` for? *but when I try to access the all the routes* - where? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. `global.router =` is a bad practice. This is what modules are for.

Answer (score 1):

```
app._router.stack.forEach(function(r){
  if (r.route && r.route.path){
    console.log(r.route, r.route.path)
  }
})
```

Can you make sure by consoling if you're getting list of all routes in `app._router.stack`? 
If yes, then you can map through it by using forEach.

**Make sure you have express version 4.x**

Comment: Thanks for it.. I have also did the same

Comment: Please check this as answer so it can be helpful for other developers as well.